# preselect radio button based on database value in Laravel 7.24

Tags: laravel

I am trying to pre-select a radio button, based on the value present in the database, and so far none of the other Stackoverflow answers could help with my problem.

**The problem is, the value present in the database is NOT selected in the form view**

Here is my code.

**Blade**

```
div class="form-group ">
 <label for="gender">Gender:</label>
 <br>
 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
 <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gender" id="Female" value="Female" {{(old('gender') == Auth::user()->gender) ? 'checked' : '' }}>
 <label class="form-check-label" for="Female">
   Female
 </label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

 <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="gender" id="Male" value="Male" {{ (old('gender') == Auth::user()->gender) ? 'checked' : '' }}>
 <label class="form-check-label" for="Male">
   Male
 </label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

 <input class="form-check-input " type="radio" name="gender" id="Other" value="Other" {{(old('gender') == Auth::user()->gender) ? 'checked' : '' }}>
 <label class="form-check-label" for="Other">
   Other
 </label>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<div class="form-group ">
  <label for="gender">Gender:</label>
  <br>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input class="form-check-input text-white" type="radio" name="gender" id="Female"  value="Female" {{Auth::user()->gender=="Female" ? 'checked' : '' }} >
  <label class="form-check-label" for="Female">
    Female
  </label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

  <input class="form-check-input text-white" type="radio" name="gender"  id="Male"  value="Male" {{Auth::user()->gender=="Male" ? 'checked' : '' }} >
  <label class="form-check-label" for="Male">
    Male
  </label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
 
  <input class="form-check-input text-white" type="radio" name="gender" id="Other"   value="Other" {{Auth::user()->gender=="Other" ? 'checked' : '' }}>
  <label class="form-check-label" for="Other">
    Other
  </label>
   </div>
```

**Key change**

`{{Auth::user()->gender=="Female" ? 'checked' : '' }}`

***Add this in every radio input field. Don't forget to change the value as {=="Male"},etc.***

Answer (score 1):

Check the User Model and see if you've added the `gender` attribute in fillable Array.

Comment: I am not using Model

Comment: There will always be a User Model.  Please check that file User.php

Comment: I did that, but nothing